# MacApp (using Swift) does not terminate launched sub-process if terminated

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, process, child-process

I've a very simple MacOS Swift application which is used as a launcher to provide a dock icon. The application launches the main script. But if the application is terminated (e.g. by clicking on it and selecting "Close" in the context menu) the subprocess with the script continues to run.

How to change this behaviour to kill the child process if the application is killed. Using `pgrep` I checked and the script is executed in a subprocess:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        print("App started!\n");

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

            let process = Process()
            process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:"/usr/local/bin/node")
            process.arguments = ["./build/index.js"]
            process.currentDirectoryPath = "/Users/myaccount/basedir"
            process.terminationHandler = { (process) in
            print("didFinish")
            }
            do {
            try process.run()
            } catch {}

        }

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        print("I'll never show up\n")
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you talking about a normal application exit? If so, then it's easy. Make `process` an instance variable so you keep a reference to it and in your `appWillTeminate` handler, stop the process if it's still running.

Comment: @JamesBucanek The function `applicationWillTerminate` is never called, I checked it (hence the comment). Then your solution would work but with the function not working, it is not possible to detect when the application dies.

Comment: If you're exiting the application normally (i.e. via a Quit command) there's no reason you shouldn't get an `applicationWillTerminate` message unless your'e doing something weird (like calling `exit()` directly, or skipping a `super` call somewhere). I'd concentrate on fixing that issue first. If that can't be fixed, there are other solutions but they are (a) nontrivial and (b) most require you to modify the child process.

Comment: @JamesBucanek I create a new project in XCode and use the source I posted and if I quit the app via menu or in the dock (right click) the message is not printed. See also: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/126418 but there seems to be a fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until now I found two possible solutions, also with the help of the comments for my question:

**1.) "The proper way" - using the application quit callback**

The `Process` object can be made global/instance scope to kill it in the `applicationWillTerminate` callback. But I encountered the problem, that this function is never called. With the help of this [forum question](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/126418) I found that you need to set the following two options to "NO" in `Info.plist`:

[image: XCode Info.plist]

Then it works perfectly.

**2.) Let the child process watch the parent**

One can get the pid of the parent very easily (`ProcessInfo().processIdentifier`) give it as a parameter when launching the child and let the child watch the parent process id - when it is no longer alive, the child can kill itself. One can watch a process by running `kill -0 PID` which will raise an error if no process exists.